# display data in jsp using jstl

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

I am new to `JSTL`.I want display data from a list in `JSP`.How to do this.I tried something.I am using eclipse luna.

My `Status.jsp` file

```
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.jsp.el.*" %> 

<c:foreach items="${statusdisplay}" var="statuslist">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="input-group  col-xs-12">
                            <span class="input-group-addon iga">Screen</span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value= "${statuslist.getScreen()}" readonly>
                    </div><br>

                    <div class="input-group col-xs-12">
                            <span class="input-group-addon iga">Show</span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="${statuslist.getShow()}" readonly>
                    </div><br>
            </div>
</c:foreach>
```

My Servlet code

```
request.setAttribute("statusdisplay", statuslist);

            RequestDispatcher requestdispatcher=request.getRequestDispatcher("/Status.jsp");
            requestdispatcher.forward(request,response);
```

When i run the program without `taglib` it not showing error and also no output in jsp.
when i add `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>`
it is show No tag `"foreach"` defined in tag library imported with prefix `"c"`

How to display data??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have typo for `<c:forEach>` tag , its  `foreach` in your code . Also you can simply use variables declared in the model class as `${statuslist.screen}` and `${statuslist.show}`.

see [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)